# Change row to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT     
   dbo.[Values].Value, dbo.Definition.FieldName, dbo.Definition.DefinitionID
FROM         
   dbo.Records AS R 
INNER JOIN
   dbo.[Values] ON R.RecordID = dbo.[Values].RecordID 
INNER JOIN
   dbo.Definition ON dbo.[Values].DefinitionID = dbo.Definition.DefinitionID
```

and result is:

```
Value   FieldName   DefinitionID
1   test new    6
4   abc 6
0   test new    7
0   abc 7
34  test new    8
910 abc 8
```

etc.

I try to get this:

```
test new | abc | DefinitionID
1           4     6
0           0     7
34          910   8
```

I try to pivot this, but without success. Column `dbo.[Values].Value` is type of `nvarchar(MAX)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select [test new],[abc],DefinitionID
from
(
   -- your query here
SELECT     dbo.[Values].Value, dbo.Definition.FieldName, dbo.Definition.DefinitionID 
FROM         dbo.Records AS R INNER JOIN 
                      dbo.[Values] ON R.RecordID = dbo.[Values].RecordID INNER JOIN 
                      dbo.Definition ON dbo.[Values].DefinitionID = dbo.Definition.DefinitionID 
) src
PIVOT
(MAX(Value) for FieldName in ([test new],[abc])) p
```

Comment: sorry my bad, Value is type of NVARCHAR(MAX)

Comment: @ziks I've changed sum to max.